# Why is $F = mg + ma$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**Problem:**
Vertically dericted force F = 49 Newtons was applied to the physical body which has mass of 4 kgs. Find the kinetic energy K of the body when it reaches to the height of 10 meters above the ground.

Given:
m = 4 kg
F = 49 Newtons
g = 9,8 m/s^2 - acceleration of free fall
H = 10 meters

I've encountered this info reading about solving the problem:
"...According to the second Newton's law: **F - mg = ma**..."

Where does it come from?
I mean I know, that the second Newton's law says `a = F/m` => `F = ma`, but why does subtraction `mg` have to do with this? 

Why does F equals to summary of `mg + ma`?

P.S. I've formulated my question as understandable as I could, if something isn't clear I'm ready to clarify it

Comment: This is a bit of a "picky" point, but the problem should have said that there was a force directed vertically $upward$.  The current wording is a bit ambigous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *total force* on the body is the $F_{applied}=  49N$ directed upwards and $mg$ directed downwards.  It is the total force that is equal to $ma$. Thus
$$
ma= F_{applied}-mg.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second Law states that the net force which equals mass x acceleration also equals the sum of all forces acting on your object. Namely, $$\Sigma \vec F \equiv \sum \vec F_i =m\vec a$$

The $\Sigma \vec F$ term represents the net force, whereas $\sum \vec F_i $ represents the vector sum of all forces.

Let $\vec F_A$ be the applied force, and $m\vec g$ be the force of gravity. The $\vec F_A$ force is pulling the object up, whereas gravity acts downwards.

By calculating the net force (in the y direction), you get $\Sigma F = ma = F_A - mg$ and thus $$F_A=ma+mg$$